# Error with UITableView iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, cell

I have a `UITableView` with rows

```
-[self.friendsPhotoArray count]+1

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.friendsPhotoArray count]+1;
    NSLog(@"array val%@",[self.friendsPhotoArray count]);

}
```

Now i want to check which is the last row and make it as non-editable i.e not to perform 
`didSelect` function. Can someone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if(indexPath.row==[array count]-1)
  {
    //Do Nothing
  }
  else 
  {
    //Do Whatever You Want
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable the selection for the last row of your table view:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    // make the cell selection style none 
    }
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    // if the last row is selected do nothing.
       if(row!=count+1){
           // do functionality
       }
  }
```

Comment: No my problem is, for every other row i need to perform something in didSelect but nothing should be performed if row becomes [self.friendsPhotoArray count]+1

Answer (score 0):

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method just put the following check:

```
if (indexPath.row ==  [self.friendsPhotoArray count]+1) {

[cell setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

}
```

Comment: Its the index of your last element. From the code you have given it seems to be [self.friendsPhotoArray count]+1. So replace LAST_ELEMENT with that and try.

Comment: `[self.friendsPhotoArray count]+1` is the count of rows, so wouldn't indexPath.row have to be `[self.friendsPhotoArray count]` for it to be the last row (0 based index).  Also, if you are caching cells, you better set it to YES otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

make it as 2 sections and try ...the resuable might create problem atlast sometimes..
make one section which you need selection and another section for non selecting

Answer (score 0):

```
if (indexPath.row ==  [array count]+1) {

    [cell setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView  editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    if (indexPath.row==yourarray.count-1)
    {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    }
    else
    {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }
}
```